# Laravel. User Registration in other database

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, laravel

I have multiple database. For users, records and etc. I separated the users database for multiple app reasons.

heres my database.php

```
'default' => 'main_db',

'connections' => [
    'auth_db' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'MYLAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'auth_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '1234'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
    'main_db' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'MYLAPTOP\SQLEXPRESS'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'main_db'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'sa'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '1234'),
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],
],
```

User.php model.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $connection = 'auth_db';

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

AuthController.php, only made a few changes after php artisan make:auth

```
class AuthController extends Controller
    {


    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;


    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    protected $username = 'username';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }


    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'username' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:4|confirmed',
        ]);
    }


    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Problem is when I add new users via /register route.. It will say object not found 'users'. Its because the users table is in the 'auth_db' and it looks like the registration of laravel is still pointing to 'main_db' even though $connection is already present in the model and pointing to the database where the user table exist..

Normal query, eloquent and login function are working smoothly.. Just this register is freaking me out..

Comment: can u include your model and controller part for 'user registration' in your question?

Comment: @Sunil there it is... only made a few changes after the php artisan make:auth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this method once :

```
<?php
return array(

'default' => 'mysql',

'connections' => array(

    # Our primary database connection
    'mysql' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host1',
        'database'  => 'database1',
        'username'  => 'user1',
        'password'  => 'pass1'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),

    # Our secondary database connection
    'mysql2' => array(
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => 'host2',
        'database'  => 'database2',
        'username'  => 'user2',
        'password'  => 'pass2'
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
    ),
),
);
```

In Controller:

```
$users = DB::connection('mysql2')->create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
```

**Eloquent**

You can also define which connection to use in your Eloquent models as well!

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

protected $connection = 'mysql2';

}
```

You can also define the connection at runtime via the setConnection method

```
<?php

class SomeController extends BaseController {

public function someMethod()
{
    $someModel = new SomeModel;

    $someModel->setConnection('mysql2');

}

}
```

Comment: probably the best idea will be. not use the default /register route and make my own manual registration module... but thanks anyways.. your answer for controller enlighten me..